# Django Tables 2 Field Accessor backward relationship

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have this model structure.  (I'm using Django 1.7)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    publicID = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Origin(models.Model):
    publicID = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='origin')
    time = models.ForeignKey(TimeQuantity)

class TimeQuantity(models.Model):
    value = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
```

I need create a table of events , using django_tables2 and I'm trying something this way to show the origin time but I get nothing

```
class EventsTable(tables.Table):
    time = tables.DateTimeColumn(accessor='origin.time.value')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('time')
```

I'm not sure about the accessor because i can have many backwards relationship

Thanks

Comment: threre is no relation between your `Origin` and `TimeQuantity` models.

Comment: time = models.ForeignKey(TimeQuantity) , this is the relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, here I see that one `Event` object can be related to multiple `Origin` objects and Each has one `Time` object. I don't know if you want one object or all objects, but for all object you can try like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    publicID = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    @property
    def time_data(self):
        origins= self.origin.all()

        return ' '.join([ str(x.time.value) for x in origins])


class EventsTable(tables.Table):
    time = tables.Column(accessor='time_data')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('time')
```

Comment: Yes, but I'll add that the table doesn't know how to sort it. So be sure to set orderable to false. Otherwise, it'll crash.